# implementation of listViews and images

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

My problem is, i want to implement a activity with a list and image and in the bottom of image there is four text .When I am going to open my app it has to show one selected text with its related image and list as default.when clicking on rest of the text  it has to show their related list and images in the same activity respectively.Since i am new to android please help me out.

Here is `xml` code

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2.5"

    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainimage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/pestf"/>



    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pest Control"
            android:id="@+id/pestf"
            android:onClick="click1"
            android:clickable="true"

            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#cf0c07"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/packf"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/packf"
            android:onClick="click1"
            android:clickable="true"

            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#cf0c07"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cleaning"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/cleanf"
            android:onClick="click1"
            android:clickable="true"

            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#cf0c07"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Landscaping"

            android:id="@+id/landf"
            android:onClick="click1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#cf0c07"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lst"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ll_pest"
    android:layout_weight="2.2"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    >

</ListView>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lst"
    android:layout_weight="3.5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/border_layout">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_pest_Email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="@string/btn7"

        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon7"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#82020202" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_pest_phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="@string/btn8"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon8"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is Activity code

```
public class demo2 extends AppCompatActivity {


    TextView tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4,txtEmail,txtPhone;
    ListView lv;
    ImageView img;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo2);
        String[] adobe_products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adobe_products);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainimage);
        txtEmail=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_pest_Email);
         txtPhone=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_pest_phone);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text3);
        tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text4);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, adobe_products));
        tv1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));

        txtPhone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String mobileNo = "08042589999";
                String uri = "tel:" + mobileNo.trim();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        txtEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(demo2.this, Booknow.class);
                // sending data to new activity
                i.putExtra("flag",true);
                i.putExtra("cat",1);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    }







    public void click2(View v){
        img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.packers);
        String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item1, countries));
        tv2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
        tv1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        tv3.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        tv4.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
    }

    public void click1(View v){

        img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pestf);
        String[] adobe = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adobe_products);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item1, adobe));
        tv1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
        tv2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        tv3.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        tv4.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {


                // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
                Intent i = new Intent(demo2.this, BedbugControl.class);
                // sending data to new activity
                i.putExtra("position", position);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }
    public void click3(View v){

        img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cleaningf);
        String[] sweets = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sweets);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item1, sweets));
        tv3.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
        tv1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        tv2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

        tv4.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
    }
    public void click4(View v) {
        img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.landf);
        String[] companies = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.company);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item1, companies));
        tv4.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
        tv1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        tv2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        tv3.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_demo2, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest to not use listviews any more, but instead use recyclerviews, it encourages you to use your own custom layouts and provides a lot of freedom on view manipulation